# Sending an error message to the users in router with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The users on my website can change their passwords.

The problem is that when the server produces an error in the process I have to set a warning message and say something like this:

```
'Warning, the password couldn't be changed, please try again!'
```

I made two routes in express

```
app.get('/editMode/:user',ensureAuthUser,routes.user.editMode);
app.get('/editMode/:user/:message',ensureAuthUser,routes.user.editMode);
```

The first shows the editMode template
The second is supposed to show the editMode and a message from the server

In the editMode.js

```
var warn=null;
    if(req.params.message) warn=validWarn(req.params.warn) ?JSON.parse(req.params.message) :null;
    console.log('message value: '+req.params.message);
    console.log('warn value: '+warn);
```

In both cases when I redirect to /editMode/+'email@user.com'+/+'warning message' or 
/editMode/+'email@user.com' I get

```
console.log(req.params.message)// value: undefined
console.log(warn)// value: null
```

Why can't I send a message to the user if my db can't change the password?

EDIT 2

editMode render

```
return res.render('templates/edit_template,
                            {
                                title: title,
                                usuario: req.session.passport.user,
                                warning: warn || null,
                            })
```

in the template edit_template.jade

```
-if(warning && warning.length)
                    h2 Error: #{warning}
                -else
                    h2 success
```

Comment: This looks very hackish, and I think you're actually trying to solve a different problem: that of showing a warning message when an error occurs. Does `routes.user.editMode` render a template? If so, why not show the message that way?

Comment: the template shows the edit mode... when i change the password i have to redirect to the edit mode again..., how can i show the message by that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using sessions, I would store the warning in the session:

```
if (theErrorOccurred)
{
  req.session.warning = 'this is your warning message';
}
else
{
  req.session.warning = null;
};
res.redirect('/editMode/...');
```

And pass it to your template in `routes.user.editMode`:

```
return res.render('templates/edit_template', {
  title   : title,
  usuario : req.session.passport.user,
  warning : req.session.warning
});
```

Also check out [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) as a more elaborate way of passing around different types of messages between requests.

Comment: what happends with the other session' users

Comment: sessions are tied to one user only (`req.session` is unique and only accessible by that user).

Comment: i have a problem, i discover that when i redirect to the /editMode/ the console.log print two times... like when a process repeat two times... so i print the req.session.warning and before i set warning to null... the console print

first print: [Object]
second print: null

but im redirecting one time

Comment: @andrescabana86 not entirely sure what you mean (which `console.log`?); perhaps it warrants a new question (with your new code)?